# git - automatically suggesting which commits to squash?

Tags: git

Often when I develop, I commit changes for testing the CI system, and then later commit the reverse, maybe together with some other changes.

Is there a tool that can take N commits, look at all combinations, and figure out which ones to squash?

It seems like evaluating a pair of commits is fairly simple - if the combined commit is smaller than the individual ones, then how about squashing?

Comment: There are no tools that I know of, but if you know the commit you intend to modify you can use [`git commit --fixup`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---fixupltcommitgt) or [`git commit --squash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---squashltcommitgt).

Comment: Git has no opinion on which commits to squash... and why should it? It's your decision to make. The same idea applies to conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like evaluating a pair of commits is fairly simple - if the combined commit is smaller than the individual ones, then how about squashing?

I assume you think a commit is "smaller" if it makes fewer changes to its parent.  For the record, that's incorrect, but ok...

So instead let's say "if the combined *patch* is smaller...".  That's still ambiguous.  It could mean the combined patch is smaller than the sum of the individual patches; or smaller than the larger of the individual patches; or smaller than the smaller of the individual patches.  But every one of these rules will systematically produce either false negatives or false positives in fairly common situations.

There's nothing simple about it, and the day a source control tool starts trying to guess my intent on something like that is the day I stop using that tool.  Because I'm perfectly capable of *telling* the tool what I want.  It's not as hard as you seem to think.

As an example of support git offers for this use case, have a look at the `--autosquash` argument to `git rebase`.

Comment: It's not *hard* to tell git what to do, but it takes time that I'd rather spend on other things.

Comment: @user239558 - Ok, after you save up all the time from not typing the one required word in the commit messages for commits you know full well you'll want squashed, and deduct the time to fix the mistakes your automated tooling inevitably makes because you wanted it to read your mind, that should add up to enough to... do nothing because it's a negative total.

Comment: I don't know which commit to squash, I'd have to lookup which one to squash.  That could be automated or at least suggested.